# Nginx on Kubernetes: only one node replies

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I have deployed the nginx pod and the service in the k-cluster via a yaml.  All looks good (service, node, pods).  This supposed to make nginx available from any node (`http:/nodeA:port`, `http://nodeB:port`, etc) but  only one node replies (works).

All nodes have the firewall disabled.

All nodes identical OS.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you provide your config files (yaml files from the service, ...)?

Comment: Yes, like @chresse said. Looking at the manner in which the service is provisioned would be the first step to check it. Assuming you used a deployment, the service should be used to expose the deployment itself and not just a pod on a node.

Comment: `netstat -oanltp` in 2 nodes to check if port open.